# Elasticsearch aggregation size

Tags: elasticsearch, size, aggregation

I have this simple aggregation where I set the `size: 100`, but I have millions of documents, I would like to know how if I can return this 100 documents and another document with the sum of the others.

```
"aggs": {
    "pid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "pid",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by `the sum of the others`? Do you want to calculate the sum of values in `pid` field?

Comment: @TarasKohut I was reading here the documentation, I believe I was looking for `sum_other_doc_count`. Thank you so much for you time :)

Comment: `sum_other_doc_count` is always included in response, so you will get it automatically

Comment: @TarasKohut Yes, thank you! :)